# Android, How to change Textview on button click?

Tags: java, android, xml

How to change text on Button click ?

in android studio I have Button and Textview
I need if i press button change text to ( My Name is Hafed ) and if i press again change to ( I'm 18 years old ) and if i press again change to ( I love programming )
Provided that the texts are mixed and not arranged

Thanks to everyone who is interested

Comment: What have you tried? You can set an onClick listener to your button and maintain a flag. And then just textView. setText("your_text") depending on the last text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

global variable  `private int which = 0;`

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            switch (which) {
                case 0:
                    mTextView.setText("My Name is Hafed");
                    which++;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mTextView.setText("I'm 18 years old");
                    which++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mTextView.setText("I love programming");
                    which=0;
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```